# Install Dell Open manage Plugin for nagios core with Icinga2?

Tags: nagios, icinga2

Has anyone successfully installed the Dell open Manage plugin for Nagios core on an icinga2 installation?

What is the Nagios core install location for an installation of icinga2 on CentOS7?

I can't proceed past asking for the install location of Nagios core. Giving an invalid install location exits the install process

Plugin URL:
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/Dell-EMC-OpenManage-Plug-2Din-for-Nagios-Core/details
When I begin installing the plugin it asks for the location of the Nagios core install. Since icing is based on Nagios, would this be possible?

Comment: If you add a little more detail to the question you are more likely to get a good answer or some guidance to proceed with investigations. Maybe put some details about these kinds of things in the question: Did you proceed beyond the point where it asks for the location at all? What did you try to get past it and were there any messages? And if not is the question partially 'what would nagios core install location be for an icinga2 installation'? Also welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you can find a solution :)

Comment: William, I believe that my question is what is the nagios core install location for an installation of icinga2 on CentOS7? I can't proceed past asking for the install location of nagios core, giving an invalid install location exits the install process.

Comment: Hey Kevin, unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough about either software to answer your question. I just read it out of curiosity and think that if you add some of those details to the question it may result in a better answer or one being provider quicker. Sorry I can't actually help with your problem :(

Comment: No worries, was good advice!

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same sort of issues, also after analysing other options we concluded this software is an overhead, so we opted for the dell manager command provided by dell itself. So if your only purpose for installing this just to monitor Dell server hardware.

You may use omreport and snmp checks which give us metrics relating to *amperage, battery, esm logs, fans, hard disk, fan, overall health , memory power supply, firmware, sdcard, storage , temperature, voltage* etc. The advantage of these plugins are they do not load the dell node which needs to be monitored as they are executed from icinga satellite node( Any central remote node which is external).

There is a perl plugin here https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/check_openmanage/details

and this is another plugin which works on snmp OIDs https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/Check-the-status-of-DELL-PowerEdge-server/details .